# How do I connect to the internet wirelessly?

Tags: 11.10, wireless

So I recently bought a Asus u56e-bal7 notebook computer. It came with the following specs:
Intel core i5 processor
6.00 GB RAM
Intel Centrino Wireless-N 6150
After installing Ubuntu 11.10 I wanted to get some applications for myself and begin using my computer. The main problem i'm having is connecting to my wireless network. When I click on the icon to connect to wireless networks, it shows me the networks available but I just can't connect. I do not get any error messages, but every couple of minutes of trying waiting for it to connect, it tells me to retype my password for my network. I am fairly new to linux-based operating systems so if you have a solution try to dumb it down please. Thanks!

The output of `tail -f /var/log/messages`:

```
May 17 23:19:37 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Registering new address record for fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b on wlan0.*.
May 17 23:19:39 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:19:39 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:19:40 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: broadcasting for a lease
May 17 23:19:43 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:19:43 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:19:46 localhost kernel: [ 4747.346229] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
May 17 23:19:47 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:19:47 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:19:47 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
May 17 23:19:56 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
May 17 23:19:56 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
May 17 23:19:56 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
May 17 23:19:56 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
May 17 23:20:01 localhost cron[14995]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/run-crons && /usr/sbin/run-crons)
May 17 23:20:05 localhost dhcpcd[14986]: timed out
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 client pid 14986 exited with status 1
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (NETGEAR)
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
May 17 23:20:05 localhost kernel: [ 4766.863284] wlan0: deauthenticating from c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be by local choice (reason=3)
May 17 23:20:05 localhost kernel: [ 4766.888468] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 17 23:20:05 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'NETGEAR'.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'NETGEAR'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'NETGEAR' has security, but secrets are required.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'NETGEAR' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'NETGEAR'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'bssid' value 'c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'wep_key0' value '<omitted>'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'wep_tx_keyidx' value '0'
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 17 23:20:09 localhost kernel: [ 4770.989948] wlan0: authenticate with c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (try 1)
May 17 23:20:09 localhost kernel: [ 4770.991905] wlan0: authenticated
May 17 23:20:09 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 17 23:20:10 localhost kernel: [ 4771.011148] wlan0: associate with c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (try 1)
May 17 23:20:10 localhost kernel: [ 4771.015069] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
May 17 23:20:10 localhost kernel: [ 4771.015073] wlan0: associated
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'NETGEAR'.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> dhcpcd started with pid 15011
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: version 5.5.6 starting
May 17 23:20:10 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b on wlan0.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 17 23:20:10 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
May 17 23:20:10 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:20:10 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sendmsg: Cannot assign requested address
May 17 23:20:10 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.8
May 17 23:20:11 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b.
May 17 23:20:11 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 17 23:20:11 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Registering new address record for fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b on wlan0.*.
May 17 23:20:14 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:20:14 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:20:15 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: broadcasting for a lease
May 17 23:20:18 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:20:18 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:20:20 localhost kernel: [ 4781.298020] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
May 17 23:20:22 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:20:22 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
May 17 23:20:22 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
May 17 23:20:30 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
May 17 23:20:30 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:30 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
May 17 23:20:30 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
May 17 23:20:40 localhost dhcpcd[15011]: timed out
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 client pid 15011 exited with status 1
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) started...
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable') [70 120 5]
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed for access point (NETGEAR)
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <warn> Activation (wlan0) failed.
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Timeout) complete.
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): deactivating device (reason 'none') [0]
May 17 23:20:40 localhost kernel: [ 4801.083162] wlan0: deauthenticating from c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be by local choice (reason=3)
May 17 23:20:40 localhost kernel: [ 4801.105483] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
May 17 23:20:40 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Auto-activating connection 'NETGEAR'.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) starting connection 'NETGEAR'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): access point 'NETGEAR' has security, but secrets are required.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none') [50 60 0]
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) started...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none') [60 40 0]
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) starting...
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless): connection 'NETGEAR' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'ssid' value 'NETGEAR'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'bssid' value 'c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'wep_key0' value '<omitted>'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: added 'wep_tx_keyidx' value '0'
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) complete.
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
May 17 23:20:43 localhost kernel: [ 4804.988915] wlan0: authenticate with c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (try 1)
May 17 23:20:43 localhost kernel: [ 4804.990920] wlan0: authenticated
May 17 23:20:43 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
May 17 23:20:44 localhost kernel: [ 4805.010329] wlan0: associate with c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (try 1)
May 17 23:20:44 localhost kernel: [ 4805.014352] wlan0: RX ReassocResp from c0:3f:0e:17:3f:be (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
May 17 23:20:44 localhost kernel: [ 4805.014360] wlan0: associated
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'NETGEAR'.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning DHCPv4 transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> dhcpcd started with pid 15019
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b on wlan0.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost dhcpcd[15019]: version 5.5.6 starting
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
May 17 23:20:44 localhost dhcpcd[15019]: wlan0: sending IPv6 Router Solicitation
May 17 23:20:44 localhost dhcpcd[15019]: wlan0: sendmsg: Cannot assign requested address
May 17 23:20:44 localhost dhcpcd[15019]: wlan0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.8
May 17 23:20:44 localhost NetworkManager[7271]: <info> (wlan0): DHCPv4 state changed nbi -> preinit
May 17 23:20:45 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b.
May 17 23:20:45 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
May 17 23:20:45 localhost avahi-daemon[7383]: Registering new address record for fe80::d2df:9aff:fe62:4a8b on wlan0.*.
```

Comment: Can you open up a terminal and type in `tail -f /var/log/messages`, hit enter a few times so you get a nice big gap of blank, then try to connect to the network. After it fails, hit ctrl+c in the terminal to end that command, and paste whatever text showed up in the terminal into your question. It might help debug.

Comment: please can you copy and paste the terminal output of `sudo lshw -class network` into your question. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)